# Android, ActionBar tabs state detection

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBar tabs navigation (using action bar sherlock).

How to detect the current state of the tab bar (stacked, embedded or drop-down list) ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API call for this purpose.

---

**Warning: The following approach may stop working in future**

There are some reflection tricks though:

```
public boolean hasEmbeddedTabs(ActionBar actionBar){
    Boolean embedded = false;
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl");
        Field f = c.getDeclaredField("mHasEmbeddedTabs");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        embedded = f.getBoolean(actionBar);
        f.setAccessible(false);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp","Not a fair play",e);
    }
    return embedded;
}
```

And for knowing the collapsed state:

```
public boolean areTabsCollapsed(ActionBar actionBar){
    Boolean collapsed = false;
    try {

        Class c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl");

        Class c2 = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView");
        Method m = c2.getDeclaredMethod("isCollapsed");

        Field f2 = c.getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
        f2.setAccessible(true);
        Object scrollView = f2.get(actionBar);
        if(scrollView != null){
            collapsed = (Boolean) m.invoke(scrollView);
        }
        f2.setAccessible(false);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. and what about the drop-down list state??